# I need to restart NetBeans after each PHP debug session and don't know why?

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

- NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201705191307)
- PHP 5.5.38 (due to legacy application)
- Chrome 66.0.3359.170 (Official Build) (64-bit)

In the last few days my NetBeans debug stops working after one debug run and will only debug after I restart NetBeans. I've tried disabling all Chrome extensions other than NetBeans Connector and tested if restarting browser and stack would help but only restarting NetBeans works. It will also freeze up in the middle of a debug.

I have not touched php.ini

This is killing my productivity. Has anyone had this problem and how did you fix it?

**UPDATE**

I set up [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and debugging works fine so this must be a NetBeans issue.

**Unchanged php.ini** (same settings that worked last week)

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = C:\xampp_php_5.5.38\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.1-5.5-vc11.dll
xdebug.idekey = netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:/xampp_php_5.5.38/xdebug"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.remote_host = 192.168.1.114
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:/xampp_php_5.5.38/tmp"
xdebug.remote_log = "c:/xampp/tmp/xdebug/xdebug_remot.log"
xdebug.show_local_vars = 9
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:/xampp_php_5.5.38/tmp"
```

Comment: Yeah, it's a NetBeans issue AFAIK. I have the same problem :/

Answer (score 0):

Derp, I 'fixed' it by removing xdebug.remote_autostart=1 from my xebug.ini file, see [nginx php-fpm xdebug netbeans can start only one debug session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229757/nginx-php-fpm-xdebug-netbeans-can-start-only-one-debug-session/36092849) .